# Orderwise match with batch and qty

Tags: excel

I have a problem with Excel sheet.

```
Col-A       Col-B  Col-C
Order.No    Batch   Qty
123451       211    5
123451       212    30
123451       213    50
123461       311    40
123471       411    50
123471       511    80
123481       611    20
123491       612    30
```

In col-A 123451 is repeating 3 time and 123471 2 time. I would like to max value from Col-3 and show batch No in front of it but only match 123451 order no.

like:

```
Order.No     Batch     Qty
123451        213       50
123461        311       40
123471        411       80
123481        611       20
123491        612       30
```

As per this result you can see that Order.No-123451 find max value Qty and paste value batch-No as per maximum value criteria. Remove duplicate Order No. The data can more than this. This is just example.

Comment: its a requirement of goods record in warehouse, each order has more then 1 batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by doing the following:

1. Sorting the entire data set by `Order No.` (ascending or descending, it doesn't matter), then by `Qty` (this **must** be descending)
2. Use Excel's Remove Duplicates tool (found on the Data tab of the ribbon)
3. In the window that appears **DE**-select all options except `Order No.`

That should leave you with 1 row per Order No., with that row being the one with the largest Qty value.